# NLP to generate input for a C++ Application

Tags: python, c++, nltk

one of my C++ application does some mathematical analysis on  trading strategies[more than 10000]. It calculates averages profit or loss ,volatility,sharp ratio etc for these strategies.
now I want a user can simply write his queries in English i.e.

> show strategies which are making profit in January 2016.

I found NLTK library to process Natural Language but unable to understand how to map these queries to the input of my C++ application without using so many if else conditions.

please help me for moving into right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by pretending that your users will use an extremely small set of simple sentence templates. Solve that case, then call it done.

Comment: Thanks for ur reponse @alexis, yes trying that as I am a beginner in the field of NLP so unable to find correct direction. so far what I have done is tokenizing , then removing stop words and then searching for conditions like 'profit more 100'. now using this I can make a query but not sure is this d correct way?

Comment: Nobody here can tell you how to solve this. Natural Language Understanding is an open problem-- and the holy grail of nlp. If you haven't done enough research to find that out, my advice is to skip that feature and provide a traditional query interface instead.